# My Touchpad in Ubuntu Doesn't Work, tried to disable/enable using xinput but shows error

Tags: touchpad

```
xinput list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
**⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]**
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_1.3M             id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 413c:8161                             id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]


I was suggested to disable using `xinput disable 4` command, but it throws an error :


X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
Serial number of failed request:  20
Current serial number in output stream:  21
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is this: try to disable your touchpad from BIOS. The id of your tp is going to change randomly and disabling it by grepping from a shell script is really flaky.

Comment: How to disable touchpad from Bios in Dell Inspiron.